# Questions about timestamp (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm wondering what is faster.

I need to compare the number of seconds between now and a datetime in my table.
The type of my column is Timestamp, is it the best way? Cause im wondering what's the difference between timestamp and an int? Or should I use datetime?

cause all I want is something like that: 1314288065 
so I would do the time now - 1314288065 and it would give me the number of seconds.

Thank you

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months after, finaly I use int cause it's more easy to work with this for time zones and it's already in the format I want.But all the other dates in this project are in datetime.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you're storing time, store it as a datetime.

Right now you'll only need the difference in seconds, but later you'll want to format the difference nicely in weeks/days/hours/... and you'll start reinventing the wheel. You're not storing strings/ints as BLOBs either, are you?

Comment: No but actually I'm not supposed to format it, it's only to calculate and no user will see it.

Comment: Don't you think it's gonna be more easy unix_timestamp cause I work with timezones.

Comment: @Marc, Konerak's advice is _a priori_ sound: datetime type is generally handled efficiently, space-wise and processing-wise by mySQL or other modern DBMSes.  A good rule of thumb is to adopt data types and more generally relational schemas which match closely the semantics of the underlying application/data.  So, unless you have specific and justified concerns about scaling, performance at large etc. it is probably a good idea to use `datetime`.  To be sure... there are instances when one needs stray from this simple approach, but these only arise with huge datases and/or particular uses.